# Initialize interface type array in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created interface with name Test in Angular 11

```
 export interface Test {
      id:number;
      name:string;
    }
```

Then I have exported the interface and create its array with name of ProvinceAllStudent

```
import { Test } from './../../../student/Models/test';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Province } from 'src/app/student/Models/Province.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-general-statistic',
  templateUrl: './general-statistic.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./general-statistic.component.css']
})
export class GeneralStatisticComponent implements OnInit {
Provinces:any[];
ProvinceAllStudent:Test[]=[];

  constructor(
) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
 this.CalculateProvinceStudents()
  }
  CalculateProvinceStudents()
  {
     for(let j=0;j<5;j++)
     {
      this.ProvinceAllStudent[j].id=j;
      this.ProvinceAllStudent[j].name='A';
     }
  }

}
```

when I run the application I got the error

> core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'id')
> at GeneralStatisticComponent.CalculateProvinceStudents (general-statistic.component.ts:23)

Comment: Your loop (let j=0;j<5;j++) is going from index 0 to 4, but ProvinceAllStudent is empty.

Comment: I want to initial the ProvinceAlStudent array using loop

Comment: In the body of the for loop, You should create a Test object, and then assign it to the array index: ---------->

let t : Test = {id: j, name: 'A'};

this.ProvinceAllStudent[j] = t;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `this.ProvinceAllStudent[j]` is `undefined` and you try to assign a value to a property of it. (`undefined` does not have the `id` and `name` properties, so an exception is thrown.)

I suggest to use `push` method of the array. For example

```
for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  this.ProvinceAllStudent.push({ id: j, name: 'A' });
}
```

Or as alternative an alternative you can add elements by index this way:

```
for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  this.ProvinceAllStudent[j] = {id: j, name: 'A'};
}
```

Comment: but if i want to access 0 index value how i can thanks

Comment: `this.ProvinceAllStudent[0]` works, `push` starts to add the values from the 0th index.

Comment: Thanks for solving the problem Milan Tenk

Comment: I'm glad, that I could help! Please accept the answer. ;)

Comment: ok the push method will insert new item to array can you explain that if i want to insert new item in specific index of an array

Comment: @MehrabShaida I updated the answer with the assignment based on index.

Answer (score 2):

you need to create the object first before modifying it in the array

```js
this.ProvinceAllStudent.push({
  id: j,
  name: 'A'
})
```

Comment: but I want to initial array an index base thanks